# javax validation : group several annotation on the same group

Tags: java, javax.validation

Is it possible for an attribute to group several javax validations on the same group without repeating the declaration ?

here is a valid example :

```
@Data
public class Poc {

    @NotNull(groups = {NameForm.class})
    private String name;

    @NotNull(groups = {DataForm.class})
    @Min(value = 0, groups = {DataForm.class})
    @Max(value = 10, groups = {DataForm.class})
    private int nbre = -1;

}
```

what I want to do is to find if it is possible to write something like this:

```
@Data
public class Poc {

    @NotNull(groups = {NameForm.class})
    private String name;

    @Groups(DataForm.class)
    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 0)
    @Max(value = 10)
    private int nbre = -1;

}
```